# Putty: Get info from process running with nohup

Tags: javascript, node.js, putty

Usually I would start my js file with `nodejs bot1.js`
But now I use nohup so the process is running even if I close putty.

When I start the process with `nodejs bot1.js` I would see what the bot was doing.

Example:

Tradeoffer incoming

Accepted tradeoffer

But with nohup I don't get that info - is there a command for this?

Sorry if the question is kinda confusing. Didn't find anything on Google.

Comment: You can write it into some log file `> /var/log/app.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a out file **nohup.out** if you don't mention one, in same directory that you executed your command in.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the logs into the file

```
nohup node app.js >> /var/log/app.log 2>&1&
```

It will append logs into app.log file.